# Redirecionar ou remover function.include com .htaccess no Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, htaccess, funções, include

Gostaria de saber se há como eu redirecionar o erro 404 de vários artigos que vem acontecendo, o exemplo é o seguinte:

http://meu-site.com/artigo-1/function.include
http://meu-site.com/artigo-2/function.include

Isto ocorre em vários artigos, é possível com .htaccess eu redirecionar este erro para o artigo correto, ou algum código para remover este /function.include?

Obrigado.

Comment: Você precisa descobrir oque está inserindo esse "function.include" pode ser algo na functions.php ou algo nos permalinks.
Só fazer um htaccess pra tirar isso não ia resolver o problema, só maquiar ele

Comment: Obrigado Daniel, vou verificar.

Comment: Conseguiu achar o problema?